# AJAX issues, no response or "access is denied"

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, response

What could it mean if I make an ajax request with the jQuery .load() and I get no response at all in firefox or chrome, and in ie8 I get an error saying "Access is Denied"?

Comment: @user278457 use firebug in firefox and see what is happening

Comment: I used firebug, completely blank response. The issue was the "same origin policy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading a page that's in a different domain (example: www.yoursite.com and you're trying to load "yoursite.com" or even "google.com"), then you are getting a [cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) prevention error.

Comment: This is not XSS, which involves Party A tricking Party B into visiting Party C's website using a URL designed to exploit a security hole in Party C's website that allows arbitrary code to be added to it.

Comment: Why, is it wrong? (reads…). No, it backs up what I said. It is about a subset of code injection vulnerabilities, not about browsers stopping authors from making cross domain HTTP requests. An XSS vulnerability would allow the same origin policy to be bypassed — quite the opposite of having a request blocked by the same origin policy!

Comment: @David: You're right, but isn't the policy there to prevent XSS?

Comment: No. It stops a different kind of attack against a third party site.

Comment: OMFG.
*it.never.gets.any.easier!*

but, again, thanks guys. Today I've fallen in love with stack overflow. Saved my coding life twice.

Comment: yeah, I put in www. in front of my domain and it all worked. Funny that IE is what tipped me off to thinking it might be something outside of my code that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It usually means you are trying to violate [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and request data from a different host.

Answer (score -1):

try accessing your data through a php proxy like this: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216729.html

with jQuery you can then send a request to your/relative/path/to/proxy.php?proxy_url=http://www.domain.com/yourdata

Comment: Don't use a proxy that doesn't put strict limits on what URIs can be requested. Otherwise you open yourself up as a middleman for attacks of third party sites and for spammers to mask their own URIs with.

Comment: You're right. But you can prevent attacks by checking the URL in your PHP-Script before accessing it.